# JSPM / Aurelia / Bootstrap 4 can't find jQuery

Tags: aurelia, jspm, twitter-bootstrap-4

So I have an aurelia setup using jspm. I have install Bootstrap 4 like so:

`jspm install npm:bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.2`

Then in main.js I did:

```
import 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap';

export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .developmentLogging();

  //Uncomment the line below to enable animation.
  //aurelia.use.plugin('aurelia-animator-css');
  //if the css animator is enabled, add swap-order="after" to all router-view elements

  //Anyone wanting to use HTMLImports to load views, will need to install the following plugin.
  //aurelia.use.plugin('aurelia-html-import-template-loader')

  aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot());
}
```

I even tried `import $ from 'jquery'` but when I spin up the aurelia skeleton with BS4 I get:

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
```

I can go to the console and do $ and it returns the jquery stuff. I think it is a race condition but not sure how to fix?

EDIT: System.config

```
System.config({
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: "none",
  paths: {
    "*": "dist/*",
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*"
  },
  meta: {
    "bootstrap": {
      "deps": [
        "jquery"
      ]
    }
  },
  map: {
```

Comment: show the lines of your config.js that contains something related to "bootstrap"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `jspm install bootstrap=github:twbs/bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.2`

There are problems installing `bootstrap` with `jspm` from `npm:` ([see here](https://github.com/jakeNiemiec/jspm-cli/blob/0.17/docs/publishing-packages.md#publishing-jspm-style-packages-to-npm)).

See [this file](https://github.com/jakeNiemiec/jspm_bootstrap/blob/master/src/index.js#L2) for how to import it (from [this project](https://github.com/jakeNiemiec/jspm_bootstrap)).

Update: [here is the Pull Request that should fix this.](https://github.com/jspm/registry/pull/916)

Comment: I tried it via github install. Still getting the same problem. I noticed they had in packages a map to jquery. So I tried that as well `"map": {
        "jquery": "npm:jquery@3.0.0",`. Unfortunately still gripes about jquery not present. My main js just simply has `import 'bootstrap';`

Comment: I also tried `import bootstrap from 'bootstrap';` I also added the overrides to match yours and destroyed my jspm_packages folder and did a new jspm install

Comment: Got it working my doing your steps and downgrading to jquery 2.2.4.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue recently as well. Try installing jquery 2, instead of jquery 3. Apparently jquery 3 doesn't hang itself off window when it's imported as a module the same as it does in jquery 2. Bootstrap 4 doesn't apparently doesn't request it as a dependency either.

Comment: I just tried going back to jquery 2.2.0 still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to load jQuery from a CDN in the HEAD section of your index.html:

```
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"   integrity="sha256-JmvOoLtYsmqlsWxa7mDSLMwa6dZ9rrIdtrrVYRnDRH0="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Taken from [https://code.jquery.com](https://code.jquery.com/). Use a different version of jQuery if you need. This is actually a better deployment strategy IMHO anyway because you will get more concurrent downloads (better parallelism) in the browser by loading libraries from CDNs.

Comment: firstly, Aurelia is pushing for e2e testing, so having to go off and grab a library off the net each time is poor practice when the problem should be solved with jspm. Secondly, Aurelia is heavily pushing toward electron apps; so again, do you really want end-user having to be connected to the net all the time? That said, it might be useful as a temporary fix for now.

Comment: @MeirionHughes good point about Electron, but those apps behave differently by default and would require different solutions across the board. But I don't believe e2e tests would be adversely affected by using CDN. It's a better solution at runtime for a web application (better than bundling jQuery) because of its ability to download concurrently along with scripts from other domains.